# My windows 8.1 is installed through legacy (I can't use UEFI) what are the steps to dual booting with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, bios

All the guides I have seen involve UEFI, however my Windows 8.1 has been downloaded in Legacy mode. How exactly do I dual boot with Ubuntu.

- I have set a 100GB empty partition.
- I have downloaded Ubuntu but haven't yet placed it on my USB as i'm not sure which method I should use.

Thanks

Comment: All you have to do is run the installer. Since you're using UEFI, no fancy steps are needed.

Comment: I'm not using UEFI, so do I just move the download to the USB? Do I need to make it bootable?

Comment: Yes, that is how you install Ubuntu. (You have to put it on USB for DVD regardless of if you're dual-booting or not. It's how you install Ubuntu.)

Comment: A BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation of Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 will be just like a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode installation of Ubuntu and Windows 7, from a dual-boot perspective. Following instructions intended for Windows 7 (which usually assume BIOS) should work fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Run boot-repair on a live cd/usb: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

If you have not installed ubuntu yet, ubuntu will install eveything that is needed for dual boot when you do that.